# Can virtual functions be realized by implicit type conversion? Or how can I do a subclass-dependent type conversion?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, type-conversion

Consider two classes `class B` and `class C`, each having one `int` type `private` member, a constructor that sets the `int` member to zero, and an `operator++()` member function, such that `B b; ++b` increases the `int` member by 1, and `C c; ++c` increases the member by 10. This is then a classic example of polymorphism. We can derive `class B` and `class C` from a common abstract base `class A`, which has a pure virtual member function `operator++()=0`. When the concrete `operator++()` functions are defined for both `class B` and `class C`, we can use `A& a=b; ++a` to increase (the `int` member of) `a` by 1, and `A& a=c; ++a` to increase `a` by 10.

Now the situation is slightly more complicated. Suppose we have

```
  class B{
    private:
      int n;
    public:
      B(int b=0) {n=b;}
      void output() {cout<<n<<endl;}
      operator int&() {return n;}
  };

  class C{
    private:
      int n;
    public:
      C(int c=0) {n=c;}
      void output() {cout<<n<<endl;}
      C& operator++() {n+=10; return *this;}
  };
```

such that the `B b; ++b` operation is not done by a member function `operator++()`, but via an implicit type conversion of `b` to an `int&` reference to its internal `int` member and then the `++` operator of type `int`. Then I find that polymorphism no longer works.

```
  class A{
    protected:
      int n;
    public:
      A(int a=0) {n=a;}
      void output() {cout<<n<<endl;}
      virtual A& operator++()=0;
  };

  class B:public A{
    public:
      operator int&() {return n;}
  };

  class C:public A{
    public:
      C& operator++() {n+=10; return *this;}
  };
```

The above code only works for `A& a=c; ++a` but not `A& a=b; ++a`. The pure virtual `operator++()=0` of the common base `class A` is inherited to `class B` and remains purely virtual, so that `class B` becomes abstract and can no longer define any objects, even if `++b` is in fact doable via the type conversion.

Suppose the class-dependent type conversion is some feature I want, because maybe the conversion is expensive and I don't want it to happen to `class C`, but somehow I have no choice but to do it for `class B`. I want my code to be smart by using some kind of "polymorphism" (even though a direct one fails here). Does anybody see a way to do this subclass-dependent type conversion in C++? I mean, can it happen that when I do `++a`, it is converted to `int` and then `++`ed if `a` is a `B`, but is directly `++`ed by the member function if `a` is a `C`?

Comment: I am all lost by the time I reach the end of the question. Can you put it in a more readab;e way ?

Comment: There are no virtual methods and no base class A in the code provided. Is that intentional?

Comment: Sorry. I've just added back the part of the code with inheritance.

Comment: I also tried deleting the virtual `operator++()` from the base `class A`. Then what happens is that both `B b; ++b` and `C c; ++c` work in their own ways (via type conversion and member function, respectively), but one can neither do `A& a=b; ++a` nor `A& a=c; ++a`. That loses the whole point of polymorphism.

Comment: You seemingly want the language to read your mind. It is not designed to do so. Just don't omit operator++ from B. Define one with the totally obvious (to you) implementation.

Comment: The point is not only to achieve different results for different subclasses, as in the classic polymorphism, but also to teach to code to use different ways of getting such results. This is useful when a clever method (direct member function) is only applicable to a subclass, while in other cases one has to do the slower type conversion.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)

Example:

```
template <class T>
class Base
{
private:
    int n;
public:
    T& operator++() {n+=10; return *this;}
    ...
};

class C : public Base<C>
{
    ...
};
```

Note: this is only for code reusage and has no common base class (because each is different because of the template)

If you need a common base class you can do it by 3 classes

```
class Base
{
protected:
    int n;
};


template <class T>
class BaseOperator : public Base
{

public:
    T& operator++() {n+=10; return *this;}
};

class C : public BaseOperator<C>
{
    ....
};
```

Comment: I just added back the part of the code with inheritance and some comments below the question. I hope the previously incomplete question did not confuse you. Sorry.

Comment: I understand your first code now. It is equivalent to deleting the virtual `operator++()` function from `class A`. Then all codes written for `class A` get reused by `class B` and `class C`, but no polymorphism via `++a` is allowed that way.

Comment: It was mostly meant as a concept to use. Not a complete solution. But the general CRTP concept here may be considered. E.g. you can try returning a `Base&` instead of a `T&` and see if this helps your need and see if you can adapt this concept to the other operations you use

Answer (score 0):

If the subclass type is to be determined at run time, i.e. whether `a` is a `B` or `a` is a `C` is not known at compile time, there seems to be no mechanism yet in C++ that allows this kind of subclass-dependent type conversion. Even the following code is not going to work:

```
  #include <iostream>
  using namespace std;

  class B{
    protected:
      int n;
    public:
      B(int b=0) {n=b;}
      void output() {cout<<n<<endl;}
      operator int&() {return n;}
  };

  class C: public B{
    public:
      C& operator++() {n+=10; return *this;}
  };

  int main(){
    B b; C c; ++b; b.output(); ++c; c.output();
    B& a1=b; ++a1; B& a2=c; ++a2;
    a1.output(); a2.output(); return 0;
  }
```

This code tries to use the mechanism that a member function overrides type conversion. It works for `++b` and `++c` and `++a1`, but not `++a2`. Even though `a2` is in fact a `C`, the compiler does not know that at compile time, so `a2` is still first type-converted to `int&` and then `++`ed, i.e., the compiler still treats `a2` as a `B` even though it is in fact a `C`.

The virtual function mechanism can only dynamically decide which version of a function to call, but cannot choose to avoid calling that function altogether and supersede it with some other function. So even if `virtual` is added to the `operator int&()` of `class B`, `a2` is still type-converted as `class B`, because `class C` does not have its new definition of type conversion. Future C++ versions may need to enrich its variant type (type determined at run time) mechanisms.